# Unset/Reset editor set by edit-sources (propably set by select-editor)

Tags: linux, debian, apt, editors

After running `edit-sources`, I was asked to select an editor:

```
$ sudo apt edit-sources

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
  3. /bin/ed
```

I'd like to get this promt reproduceable for documentation purpose again. This means, the editor selection is shown after calling `edit-sources` like it was at the first time.
I don't know where the selection there was set, `$EDITOR` is empty. I guess that [`select-editor`](https://www.commandlinux.com/man-page/man1/select-editor.1.html) was called in the background since the corresponding file exists:

```
$ cat ~/.selected_editor
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/bin/nano"
```

So I deleted that file, but still no promt. `env | grep -i editor` doesn't show any result, also with grep to nano (which was set as editor on the first `edit-sources` call. It has to be savede on another place, because calling `sudo apt edit-sources` automatically opens nano instead of the editor selection.

**My question is: What additional things are required to be done to let `edit-sources` show the selection question again?**

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, this would do the trick:

```
sudo rm /root/.selected_editor
```